# Burg theme not working

Tags: themes, burg

I have successfully installed burg in order to replace that ugly grub since I have a dual boot. So it shows perfectly. Using Gurb Manager I even managed to remove unwanted entries. But I can't install any theme: I open super-boot-manager, then I select my right theme for burg, double click on apply changes, but when I click the button burg-emu or restart the system the theme isn't changed.

This is my burg.cfg:

```
### BEGIN /etc/burg.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/burgenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="Windows 7"
if [ ${prev_saved_entry} ]; then
  set saved_entry=${prev_saved_entry}
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then
    saved_entry=${chosen}
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
set gfxmode=1680x1050
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5d793aff-d821-4f47-91a4-4020a914fd8e
if loadfont /usr/share/burg/unicode.pf2 ; then
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod vbe
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,5)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5d793aff-d821-4f47-91a4-4020a914fd8e
  insmod gfxmenu
  insmod png
  set theme=($root)/boot/burg/themes/Lightness/theme.txt
fi
if terminal_output gfxterm ; then true ; else
  # For backward compatibility with versions of terminal.mod that don't
  # understand terminal_output
  terminal gfxterm
fi
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5d793aff-d821-4f47-91a4-4020a914fd8e
set locale_dir=($root)/boot/burg/locale
set lang=fr
insmod gettext
set timeout=3
### END /etc/burg.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/burg.d/10_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Elementary OS" --class elementary --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --group group_main {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5d793aff-d821-4f47-91a4-4020a914fd8e
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-031300-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-031300-generic root=UUID=5d793aff-d821-4f47-91a4-4020a914fd8e ro  quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1680x1050-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-031300-generic
}
### END /etc/burg.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/burg.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###
menuentry "Windows 7" --class windows --class os {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1e9c75749c7546f5
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/burg.d/30_os-prober_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/burg.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/burg.d/40_custom ###
```

Comment: If I remember right, the BURG theme is selected at boot time and is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching your program through the terminal to see if there are any errors while you try and change the theme?
Also maybe you should try and launch super-boot-manager as root to make the changes?
`sudo super-boot-manager`

Comment: The terminal running super-boot-manager doesn't reveal anything interesting, only `grep: /etc/burg.d/50_iso: No such file or folder`.